# Sharing Source Control / Build Artifacts in Cruise Control .NET

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I've got one repository with multiple projects underneath it's directory structure, I'm looking to set up a unique CC.NET Project for each project in my repository.

There's two unique challenges I'm running into, and I want to make sure I can do this without shooting myself in the foot.

My main concern is source control, I can duplicate the source control block with the `<cc:define>` pre-processor block, that's fine. I'm concerned about source control conflicts however. If two projects are running at the same time, one might update the source control while the other is building. Is there a way to share this source control resource safely?

I had thought about having a special project that's responsible for all the CI triggering from source changes / periodic intervals / etc... and have the other projects trigger off of that project's completion. This seems a bit shady to me.

The other issue is dependencies, I know that CC.NET can use Solution files (and it's often reccomended), the problem here is that I'd really prefer to not build my library projects once for each project in CC.NET.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so please mark the answer as so or provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a queue, that way when a project is building/updating source it blocks all other projects from doing so.

Otherwise you could create a new report on disk for each ccnet project - Which does undermine what you ideally want to do.

The advantages however are that one ccnet project doesn't block another - if it takes a while to build/update

Comment: The issue wasn't build sequence, it's run sequence, I wanted to share the source control checkout and compile results from previous builds so my core library doesn't get built for each child library. I've moved on from CC.NET so I'll let this comment sit here for a bit before I delete the question so you get an answer.